# colored Metal material

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I did make an xperia XZ mobile phone on blender and everything worked well until I started with materials. I could not make that Metal material with right colores. And when I used a image texture I lost shine effect from glossy node. I want a result as like as the one on pictures down.

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding correctly. Also not sure what render engine you are using. If its cycles I recommend downloading 2.79 (if you don't have it already) and use the Principled BSDF shader with the Metallic set to 1 and play with the roughness value until you are happy with the results.

Also keep in mind you need a light source to actually reflect the light. I used an HDRI in this image but you can just use a plane mesh and put an emission shader on it. Then position it how you like best.

[image]

Comment: For metallic materials you should also bring up the value for specular tint.

Comment: Perfect result. Thank you guys. I used the glossy shader and forgot to add an HDR environment in mine.